# Image showed up black on device > Image View Android

Tags: android

I am still fairly new with Android Development. I am using Android Studio for this app, and when I start a brand new application, and when I add an image in, either jog, or png, the image turns out Black on the device when I compile and test it. Is there a reason for this? I don't think I need to share my code as, like I said, I am starting a brand new project.

Here is my XML file.

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/splash2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


}
```

Everything else is pretty normal... no other edits.

Comment: Where did you add that image give the code

Comment: Can you post your full xml code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android studio there are mipmap folders and we generally place images in these folders and in xml we specify image `src` as `@mipmap/splash2` and also make sure that another view is not coming on top of your image view

Comment: Thank you!!! What is the drawable section for then? What would we put in there? Also, what is a good rule of thumb for making images are multiple devices? backgrounds, buttons, etc etc.

Comment: Generally we place shape drawables that are created using xml

Comment: The drawable section is used to hold icons/images and other xmls for shapes and gradients. A good rule would be to create different drawable folders for different screen densities and sizes (i.e drawable-hdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-sw600dp etc) and place the respective icons/images in them.

Comment: awesome. Thank you guys!!